# How can I make this lettering/typographic shape better?

Tags: typography, logo, line-art, lettering

I made this effect in Illustrator using the line tool, Zig Zag tool and then expanding the line to a path.

I want the top line of the 'E' to join perfectly with the line in the 't'.

I have almost got it but it looks weird still. I want it to look as smooth as possible.

[image]

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Check how your curve compares to the bottom curve of the E. Though I would say: baselines is for whimps! Try to pull the t up, and make the stroke from the E horizontal.

Comment: there's no magic to it. Just keep dickering with the handles until the curve sweetens out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your points look something like this:

[image: Vertical middle point]

Two ways to improve this curve. First, angle the middle point so that the handles flow into the handles from the other points:

[image: Angled middle point]

Or, remove the middle point entirely. Less points = less opportunities to create jaggedness, if you can still get the look you want:

[image: No middle point]